# Создание CSS Grid сетки которая гарантированно будет состоять из квадратов

Tags: css, css-grid

Я хочу создать grid который будет занимать

- Весь экран по длине
- Состоять из 7 столбцов
- Состоять из такого количества строк, чтобы ширина одной ячейки была равна ее длине

Примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Подробнее. Желательно картинкой.

Comment: Добавил картинки

Comment: Нужен грид или просто полоски?